# Error when using self static function

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

```
class Assets {
    public static $my_static = '';    

    public static function custom_js()
    {
        return self::add_custom_js();
    }

    public static function add_custom_js($str)
    {
        return self::$my_static = $str;
    }
}
```

And php

```
<?php
Assets::add_custom_js("ABC");
?>
<html>
 ...
 <?php echo Assets::custom_js(); ?>
 ...
</html>
```

Error can't show data string is "ABC"

Comment: you are not passing the argument when calling add_custom_js() inside custom_js()

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to return `$my_static` value to get `ABC` in `echo Assets::custom_js();`. Consider following:

```
class Assets {
    public static $my_static = '';    

    public static function custom_js()
    {
        // return self::add_custom_js();
        return self::$my_static; //This is what you want i believe
    }

    public static function add_custom_js($str)
    {
        return self::$my_static = $str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return `$my_static` from `custom_js()` so  Your class should be as follow:

```
<?php
class Assets {
    public static $my_static = '';    

    public static function custom_js()
    {
        return self::$my_static; //<-------------change this line
    }

    public static function add_custom_js($str="")
    {
        return self::$my_static = $str;
    }
}
?>
```